# How to get sine wave moving in jfreechart?

Tags: java, animation, jfreechart

I have moving sine wave in my project. I'm using jfreechart. I tried for a long but I can't find where is the mistake.
In my project there is a SimulationPanel where I keep sliders to adjust frequency, amplitude and phase. Another class is Animation where I keep chart and animate it.

```
public void go(String type) {  
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate( (new Runnable() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(active) {
            l = dataset.getSeries();
            for (int k = 0; k < l.get(0).getItemCount(); k++{ l.get(0).updateByIndex(k, l.get(0).getY(k+1));
                l.get(0).updateByIndex(k, generateF(k+1));
            }
            }

    }

    }),  0, 600, MILLISECONDS);

}

public double generateF(int shift) {
    return SimulationPanel.amplitudeFSlider.getValue()*Math.sin((2*3.14*SimulationPanel.frequencyFSlider.getValue()/2000*shift*0.01+SimulationPanel.phaseFSlider.getValue()/63.7))/10000;
}
```

I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to make animated sine wave in JFreeChart*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50027077/230513).

Comment: Related examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20JSpinner) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20JSlider).